# InputStreamReader readLine method returns wrong String

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send a string from my java server to an android client over a socket. Instead of showing the correct String which would be "`OK`" the read method of the InputStreamReader returns 
"`��OK`".

The code of the server looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dOut.writeUTF("OK");
        dOut.flush();           
        dOut.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Disconnected from client number: " + id);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ThreadImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And the code of the client looks like this:

```
public void run() {
    try  {
         Socket socket = null;
         try {
              socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1978);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
         String serverRes = null;
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         ServerRes = reader.readLine();
         System.out.println(ServerRes);
         reader.close();
         socket.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a DataInputStream instead of an InputStreamReader. This is the source of your problem

```
InputStreamReader reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
String inStr = reader.readUTF();
```

Comment: Thank you, the InputStreamReader was the problem, but your code is wrong because you try to assign the DataInputStream to a Buffered Reader. The right way is to make the reader variable also a DataInputStream.

Comment: @PP_Hyperion you are correct. I have corrected my answer. Thank you!